# gRPC-Web Sending JSON as String

Tags: grpc, grpc-go, grpc-web

I need to send data of nested JSON object from gRPC-web to Backend Golang server. I ended up with converting and sending JSON as a string to the backend server and converting the string back to the JSON in the backend server. Is this a good practice or is there any other solution to transfer JSON.

Comment: Why not use protobuf instead of JSON?

Comment: I am getting data as JSON from the third party API. Also, I am storing the same in MongoDB. So if I use protobuf, I need to Convert JSON to protobuf and also protobuf to JSON.

Comment: Just to clarify, your Golang server is gRPC-based? May we see the `proto` file where you're defining your gRPC service and protocol buffer messages?

Comment: `
syntax = "proto3";
package pb;

message DemoRequest {
string json = 1;
}

message DemoResponse {
string message = 1;
}

service DemoService {
rpc Demo(DemoRequest) returns (DemoResponse) ;
}
`